# Preinstalled SNS Application

Tags: applications

I have deleted the SNS application and now im not getting any of my Facebook notifications. Is there a way of getting this appplication back on my phone? I have looked in the app market and cannot find it. Cheers

Comment: The SNS framework is part of the firmware. It's not part of an App that can be acquired via the play store.

Answer (score 4):

You either have to restore it from backup if you have one, or reflash the phone, either with a third-party ROM or an official one from your phone manufacturer. Can't go into specifics unless you mention your phone model.